# How to override __unicode__ on Django Auth.Group instance in form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-filter

I want to apply a filter to goup instance's name when in a form. Here is

#### My filter

```python
@register.filter(name='prettify_group')
def prettify_group(group):
    try:
        group = group.name
    except TypeError:
        group = group

    if group == 'sysadmin':
        return _('Sysadmin')
    elif group == 'ceo':
        return _("Chef d'entreprise")
    else:
        return group
```

### My form

```python
class InternalActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'instance' in kwargs and kwargs['instance'] is not None:
            initial['groups'] = [g.pk for g in User.objects.get(username=kwargs['instance'].username).groups.all()]
        super(InternalActorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

### My view template

This work as expected

```python
{% if groups %}
    <dt>{% trans 'Groupe (permissions)' %}</dt>
    {% for group in groups %}
        <dd class="inline-item">
        {{ field=group|prettify_group }}
        </dd>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

### My edit template

```python
    {{ form }}
```

### Question

I tried to override `__unicode__()` methode by extending the `Auth.Group` in my `core.models` with `class MyGroup(Auth.Group)` but it didn't work as there is no equivalent to `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

**But how can I apply the filter in the form?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelChoiceField` and `ModelMultipleChoiceField` allow you to override labels in select box.

First subclass field class and override `label_from_instance` method.

```
class GroupMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return prettify_group(obj)
```

Now use this field instead of standard `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in your form:

```
class InternalActorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    groups = GroupMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

This is a [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) Django feature.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to update the `choices` list from this field with the filtered values:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(InternalActorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['groups'].choices = [(gid, filters.prettify_group(name)) for gid, name in self.fields['groups'].choices]
```

But I guess it's a hackish way to do what `@catavaran` suggested.